# Restricted \write18 enabled entering extended mode error

Tags: pdftex, shell-escape

Hi I am creating pdf on my windows 8 machine. I am using texlive 2019.
While giving command pdflatex test.tex
I am getting this error. 
I have no clue why this error is happening.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No file test.aux.
[1{c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux)
 )<c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 9062 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Please guide me is there any package I have to install or any settings I need to make.

Comment: There is no error, that is a normal message.

Comment: Did you check the resulting pdf file? Does it show what you expect?

Comment: They're standard informative messages, no error.

Comment: Yes PDF is generated along with some different files like .log, .aux etc

Comment: As already said: the messages are normal. I get them too. They simply tell you about some default options.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you.